# what's the best Overdrive mode for SP gaining when using Overdrive to SP on a weapon

Tags: final-fantasy-10

i would think setting it to the mode where the overdrive increases as you attack would be good but the problem is that it seems to be relative to the amount of damage a character deals which is a down fall for Yuna so which is a good mode i can set the overdrives to to get the most SP for all participating characters

i already have an area to grind but i want to try and get the most SP out of them

Comment: Overdrive mode to the one where it charges when allies take damage.  
Triple overdrive on weapons.  
Overdrive = SP on weapons.
Kill Don Tonberry in the arena.
Profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one definitive answer for which is the best Overdrive mode since it's dependent on the character and who you're fighting.

For grinding out regular enemies that you kill pretty quickly, **Warrior** or **Slayer** is probably your best choice since you'll be doing most of the damage.

For enemies that hit you with more powerful attacks, **Stoic** or **Comrade** might be your best option for your damaging characters whereas **Healer** could be used for Yuna.

I would avoid using **Ally** since it charges very slow.  I would also avoid **Coward, Hero, Daredevil, Tactician, Avenger, Sufferer, Victor, Victim, Solo, Dancer, or Rook** since none of these are very well suited to grinding.

You can find a complete list of all the different modes [here](http://www.ffinsider.eu/final-fantasy-10/omode.php) along with how to make use of each mode.